# Car class errors

Tags: python

I am having troubles figuring out this problem. I was given 2 separate codes and this is where I am having troubles at. I am getting an error in line 38 that is "UnboundLocalError: local variable 'year' referenced before assignment" I'm not exactly sure what I am doing wrong, I am new to Python but any assistance is greatly appreciated.

```
class Car:
    def __init__(self, year_model, make, speed):
        self.__year_model = year_model
        self.__make = make
        self.__speed = 0

    ############# year_model################
    def setYear_model(self, year_model):
        self.__year_model = year_model

    def getYear_model(self):
        return self.__year_model

    ############# Make################
    def setMake(self, make):
        self.__make = make

    def getMake(self):
        return self.make

    ############# speed################
    def set_Speed(self, speed):
        if speed < 0:
            print("Speed cannot be negative")
        else:
            self.__speed = speed

    def get_Speed(self):
        return self.__speed

    ############# str ############
    def __str__(self):
        return "Make : " + self.__make + ", Model Year :" + \
            self.__year_model + ", speed =" + str(self.__speed)

    def accelerate(self):
        self.__speed = self.__speed +5

    def brake(self):
        self.__speed = self.__speed -5


def main():

    year=(input('car year: '))
    make=(input('car make: '))
    speed=0
    my_car = Car(year, make, speed)
    print('Current speed is', speed)

    #accelerate 5 times

    my_car.accelerate()
    print('My current speed:',my_car.get_speed())
    my_car.accelerate()
    print('My current speed:',my_car.get_speed())
    my_car.accelerate()
    print('My current speed:',my_car.get_speed())
    my_car.accelerate()
    print('My current speed:',my_car.get_speed())
    my_car.accelerate()
    print('My current speed:',my_car.get_speed())

    #brake five times
    my_car.brake()
    print('My current speed after brake:',my_car.get_speed())
    my_car.brake()
    print('My current speed after brake:',my_car.get_speed())
    my_car.brake()
    print('My current speed after brake:',my_car.get_speed())
    my_car.brake()
    print('My current speed after brake:',my_car.get_speed())
    my_car.brake()
    print('My current speed after brake:',my_car.get_speed())

main()
```

which then is connected to this code.

```
import ct_CarDefinition

def main():
    # Create an instance of Car
    my_car = ct_CarDefinition.Car("2008", "Honda Accord")

    print(my_car)

main()
```

Comment: What are year, make, speed in the main function where you have: `my_car = Car(year, make, speed)` ?

Comment: You are using the variable "year" before you set it somewhere in your code. The error message will tell you exactly where. (It's in the main() function).

Comment: If I just put my_car = Car() then I get a different error. "TypeError: __unit__() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'year_model' and 'make'"

Comment: As a side note, this code you were given is pretty bad—clearly written by someone who wants to force Python to be a crappy version of Java rather than by someone who actually uses Python. That's not your fault, but if this code came from your teacher… well, you may want to find a better place to learn Python.

Answer (score 3):

You're trying to use the variable `year` (and, likewise, `make` and `speed`) before you set it to anything:

```
my_car = Car(year, make, speed)

year=(input('car year: '))
make=(input('car make: '))
speed=0
```

You can't create a 2008 Honda Accord before you've asked the user for his preferred year and make unless you can somehow read the user's mind; for all you know he could ask for a 2014 Porsche Boxster. So, just create the `Car` *after* you know what care you want to create.

Also, you're trying to pass three arguments to `Car(year, make, speed)`, but it only takes two. A `Car` always starts with speed 0, so you don't have to pass it one.

```
year=(input('car year: '))
make=(input('car make: '))

my_car = Car(year, make)
```

<sub>There are some languages, called dataflow programming languages, that let you create "incomplete values" like this, so `my_car` would be an ambiguous `Car`, but as long as you don't try to use it until `year`, `make`, and `speed` are filled in, nobody cares that it's incomplete. But Python isn't such a language, nor are most other languages you're likely to use.</sub>

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
def main():
    year=(input('car year: '))
    make=(input('car make: '))
    speed=0
    my_car = Car(year, make, speed)  #use this once you have assigned values for "year", "make", "speed"
```

Also, change the following in your class definition:

```
class Car:
    def __init__(self, year_model, make, speed):        #add "speed" parameter
        self.__year_model = year_model
        self.__make = make
        self.__speed = 0
```

Also, you are not defining "accelerate" and "brake" methods in your Car class. Thus using `my_car.accelerate()` or `my_car.brake()` is going to throw an error:

```
AttributeError: Car instance has no attribute 'accelerate'
```

You can add the following methods to the Car class:

```
############# accelerate ################
def accelerate(self):
    self.__speed = self.__speed +5

############# brake ################
def brake(self):
    self.__speed = self.__speed -5
```

Also change the names to these two methods as you are calling `set_speed` and `get_speed` in your `main` method.

```
############# speed################
def set_speed(self, speed):
    if speed < 0:
        print("Speed cannot be negative")
    else:
        self.__speed = speed

def get_speed(self):
    return self.__speed
```

Output:

```
#car year: 1998
#car make: "Honda Accord"
#('Current speed is', 0)
#('My current speed:', 5)
#('My current speed:', 10)
#('My current speed:', 15)
#('My current speed:', 20)
#('My current speed:', 25)
#('My current speed after brake:', 20)
#('My current speed after brake:', 15)
#('My current speed after brake:', 10)
#('My current speed after brake:', 5)
#('My current speed after brake:', 0)
```

Comment: Good catch that the initiator was missing the speed argument.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid: Actually, I think it's the other way around. Cars are supposed to be created with speed 0 (to avoid serious injuries in the factory, I'd assume…), so the user shouldn't be passing one in.

Comment: Even after changing all of that I am still getting an error. "AttributeError: 'Car' object has no attribute 'accelerate'"

Comment: you have not defined "accelerate" in the Car class. See explanation in the answer.

Comment: I edited the original post and I am wondering what did I not change right?

Comment: make it `set_speed` not `set_Speed`